# What's the Singular term for Music?

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

I'd like to know what's the singular term of music, is it muse?

Comment: When you looked up "music", what did the dictionary say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Music*** is usually used as uncountable.

But when this noun means
"a distinctive type or category of music" 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/music) 
it is a countable noun.

So in this meaning it has both singular and plural forms (i.e., a music, some musics).

Etymologically ***MUSIC*** is connected with ***MUSE***:

"from Greek mousikē (technē) "(art) of the Muses," from fem. of mousikos "pertaining to the Muses""
(https://www.etymonline.com/).